# Does Alien actually pass the Bechdel test?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979, bechdel-test

[The Bechdel test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdel_test) originated in [‘The Rule’, a 1985 cartoon by Alison Bechdel](http://dykestowatchoutfor.com/the-rule).

In it, a character describes the test as something she uses to determine which movies she'll see:

> **One**, it has to have at least two women in it, who two, **talk** to each other about, three, something besides a **man**.

If a movie fails the test, she doesn't see it. She notes that the last movie she could actually see was 1979's *[Alien](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(film))*.

[image: The Bechdel test comic]

However, I'm not sure that *Alien* actually qualifies.

As I recall, there are two female characters: Ripley and Lambert. I don't remember them actually having a significant conversation in the film. The best I can remember is Ripley trying to get Lambert to pull it together after Captain Dallas is killed, and that's arguably a conversation about a man.

Does *Alien* actually pass the Bechdel test?

Comment: What you've posted is only half [the original comic](http://www.flickr.com/photos/zizyphus/34585797/lightbox/).  The full comic shows her reason for *Alien* passing and gives something closer to an actual punchline.

Comment: They don't have a one-on-one conversation about the monster, but they do discuss it in a group setting: "RIPLEY
                  We can't go into hypersleep with
                  that thing running loose.  We'd
                  be sitting ducks in the freezers.
                  We have to kill it first.

                                 LAMBERT
                  We can't kill it.  If we do, it
                  will spill its body acids right
                  through the hull..."

Comment: @jwodder: aha, I didn’t realise. Have you got a URL for an image of the full comic?

Comment: Ignore my comment above, the lines I mentioned were from the final script, but I just rewatched the same scene in the movie and they weren't there, either it wasn't filmed or it was edited out.

Comment: @RussellBorogove - exactly right. And there's the further premise that this is a bad thing - it may be that male experiences are more readily generalizable to women than the other way around. Furthermore, this may be true because a lack of empathy in men! If this is all true, there's nothing wrong with films failing this test, and there's certainly nothing wrong with Bechdel not liking films that fail her test. I'd say that Hunt for Red October is a GREAT movie which definitely fails this test.

Comment: There's been some chat about this over the years, and if nothing else, the fact that Alien does TECHNICALLY pass the test shows that the test is only a rudimentary rule of thumb.  The most accepted iteration of the test is that the conversation between two women must be of a certain length of time, usually a minute or so.  so that brief chat in Alien is not enough to pass. But Alien is CLEARLY a great movie about a strong woman.

Comment: Mother is certainly a character, and is woman-identifying; neither of these are strange or impossibilities within a sci-fi tale. Ripley and Mother talk about things besides a man as well.

Comment: @SillybutTrue: when did the computer identify as a gender? And it's a character? Is the motion detector a character too?

Comment: None of the characters identified their gender. Mother is played by Helen Horton as Ripley is played by Sigorney Weaver and Lambert by Veronica Cartwright. Mother has characteristics different from the motion sensor; whether the motion sensor is a character or not is not my argument, though. Mother has more in common with Ash than the motion detector; and Mother is a named character while motion detector is not.

Comment: @SillybutTrue: I still don't think Mother is a character. I don't see anything beyond what Siri does, and I don't think Siri would qualify. Mother seems like a machine without a consciousness.

Comment: MU/TH/UR 6000, named Mother is an artificial intelligence. Bechdel for purposes in sci-fi and fantasy needn’t limit to biological human beings as tested “characters.”

Comment: @SillybutTrue: "is an artificial intelligence" — is it though? What does it do that makes it a character, that other computers don't?

Comment: I’m not making the case other computers are or also aren’t characters but out of universe, Mother is a named character in a film played by an actress; it is a screen-credited character, as say HAL9000 of 2001: A Space Odyssey. In-universe, the MO/TH/UR series is a highly advanced artificial intelligence. How these elements compare to “other computers” is nonissue unrelated to anything I’m suggesting.

Comment: @SillybutTrue: "In-universe, the MO/TH/UR series is a highly advanced artificial intelligence" — you can keep stating that as much as you want, but without explaining why, it's not silly or true, it's just empty meaningless noise. Still. You keep on brother. Keep bashing your fingers on the keys. Something will happen eventually.

Comment: I don’t need to explain why. The Aliens universe defined it as such. Whine to them.

Comment: @SillybutTrue: "The Aliens universe defined it as such" — sure it did.

Comment: @PaulDWhite Glad you agree. 

Comment: @SillybutTrue: sure I do. But hey, that doesn't really matter: as you say, if Mother is credited as a character in *Alien*, that settles it. Can't argue with credits.

Comment: @PaulDWaite https://m.imdb.com/name/nm0395600/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cl9

Comment: @SillybutTrue: Huh. Looks like she was credited, but [not as a character](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5zoVONBzxs&t=142s). She's in with [the stunt coordinator and the company that trained the cat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5zoVONBzxs&t=130s). (As is the performer who portrayed the alien itself. Harsh!)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Pass.

> Ripley: "That's not our system."
>   Lambert: "I know that."

Also, this is a convo with >2 people but as part of it they exchange replies with each other:

> Lambert: What? And end up like the others? No … no, you're out of your mind!
>   Ripley: You got a better idea?
>   Lambert: Yes! I say that we abandon this ship! We take the shuttle and just get the hell out of here! We take our chances and … and hope that somebody will pick us up!
>   Ripley: Lambert ... the shuttle won't take four.
>   Lambert: Well, then why don't we draw straws and ...

and in Direcor's Cut only:

> Lambert: [slapping Ripley] You b&^*&^*!
>   Lambert: You were gonna leave us out there!

Comment: I agree with this. Also, I don't think the Bechdel test implies no males can be present; only that the two women must directly address each other about something other than males. So a group conversation with a sub-conversation between two of the women qualifies, IMO.

Answer (score 22):

[Found the script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/alien_shooting.html), and I think this scene should count, though Parker is present and has one line:

```
INT. BRIDGE

   Ripley in the Computer Annex.
    Lambert and Parker enter.

                             RIPLEY
              He's right about one thing.
              We've got less than twelve
              hours oxygen left.

                             PARKER
              It's all over.

    Gloom.

                             LAMBERT
              I don't know about the rest of
              you, but I think I prefer a
              painless peaceful death to any
              of the alternatives on offer.

                             RIPLEY
              We're not there yet.

    Lambert holds up a small card of spansules.
    Suicide pills.

                             LAMBERT
              We're not.  Huh.

                             RIPLEY
              I think we should blow up the
              ship.

                             LAMBERT
              I'll stick with chemicals if
              you don't mind.

                             RIPLEY
              We leave in the shuttle and
              then blow up the ship.
```

And, as Monty129 points out, they are technically not talking about a man if the subject is Ash, even when they discuss whether one of them has slept with him.

Comment: Nice! Regarding Ash, technically true, although given that they both believe him to be a man at that point, I think it’d be against the spirit and intention of the test to count that.

Comment: Although I think some of this exchange may have been cut from the film: see http://www.amazon.com/review/R3TAYOIZYU52VV/ref=cm_cr_pr_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0446829773&linkCode=&nodeID=&tag=

Comment: Pretty sure Ash is against the spirit of the rule. It shouldn't matter whether "he" is actually a man, but whether the women talking about him think he is a man...

Answer (score 12):

There have been a few Bechdel test questions in the last day or so. For future reference, there is an existing website that analyzes many movies under the test, at http://bechdeltest.com/

According to that website, *Alien* passes for the reasons identified above: http://bechdeltest.com/view/13/alien/

*Aliens* similarly passes, based on the multiple conversations between Ripley and Newt: http://bechdeltest.com/view/283/aliens/

*Alien 3*, however, fails the test as it lacks a second named woman: http://bechdeltest.com/view/296/alien_3/

Comment: It's not really specified as such, but a lot of people who compare against the Bechdel Test require the two women to not be children as the age difference generally skews the possible subjects of conversation.

Comment: @phantom42: It's a moot point for Aliens, since additionally Ferro and Vasquez, two female marines, talk about Ripley (if only briefly).

Comment: And, on a more tongue in cheek note, there's the exchange: "Get away from her, you bitch!" "Hsssss!" between Ripley and the Alien queen.

Comment: If Ash does not qualify as a man, I think the Alien Queen definitely wouldn't qualify as a woman. Female, yes; woman, no.

Comment: Alien 3 fails on so many levels.